# How to send class which contain Image from Android to Java Restful Web server using Retrofit

Tags: android, image, rest, retrofit

I use Retrofit to transfer Data(class) from android to Server.Generally we create **Same** class on Client and Server side which contain data type like int,String same on both side.Now I need to send **Image** in class to Server.Also I just don't want to send just image to server but I want to send class which contain 1 image as datatype.So how can I do that ?or any suggestion how can I do this with some other tool ?

Comment: @david.mihola consider "Any format" image ,because in my scene I am attaching Image from mobile phone and sending it to server.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you already have a `File` pointing to the image:

```
final File imageFile = ...;
```

Note: How to get this file depends on whether you only allow local files in your file chooser (or e. g. images that are actually in Google Drive) and on which Android version you are on, etc.

To upload the image you need to use Retrofit's `TypedFile` - here is what worked for me:

```
@POST("/api/image/upload")
@Multipart
public void submitPictureToVoting(@Part("user_id") Integer userId,
                                  @Part("image_title") String imageTitle,
                                  @Part("file") TypedFile file,
                                  Callback<UploadImageResponse> callback);
```

And then:

```
final TypedFile typedImageFile = new TypedFile("application/octet-stream", imageFile);

mApiClient.submitPictureToVoting(
    1234567,
    "This is me!",
    typedImageFile,
    new Callback<UploadImageResponse> {
        // ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is answer but by doing this we can solve proble of Retrofit easily

Hi I tried this by **Encoding Image to String** ,so that we can easily send this "String" data type like other String, & when we want image back,we can decode it.

1.Code for Encoding

Here Image taken from ImageView.

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

2.Code for Decoding

```
 byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(encodedImage, 0);
 Bitmap decodedImg= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedImg);
```